# Increase reputation for question upvotes on some sites

Tags: discussion, reputation, code-golf

On certain sites, coming up with questions is actually much more valuable than coming up with the answers.

The best example of this (and the only one that I am actually thinking of) is code golf, and there is a [discussion about this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120/rep-points-for-questions) on meta.codegolf. In light of the fact that coming up with code challenges is needed much more than coming up solutions to them (if you don't believe me, look at the [question/answer ratio](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles) on code golf as well as the worrying number of questions), shouldn't the reputation awarded to question upvotes reflect that?

Comment: I would argue that most site metas fall under this as well. (Including this site) Not because it's hard to come up with things, but because votes on the questions are used as a sign of agree and disagree.

Comment: it's a fair point, but this says more about Code Golf / Puzzles being an outlier than anything else.

Answer (score 3):

It seems going in the contrary direction reported in [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

The first step for "optimizing for pearls" was rebalancing the reputation system.

> While we value good questions (and asking a great question is absolutely an art), we want to explicitly encourage people to provide the best possible answers. Without people interested in providing good answers, the questions are moot. We know that answers have more intrinsic value than questions, and the reputation balance should reflect that.

The question asker already enjoys a substantial benefit beyond reputation gain from upvotes on their question — namely, they get great answers to their question! Thus, the asker shouldn’t need as much reputation gain.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely agree with Jeff on this -- if the asker takes the time to generalize the question to the point where it's generally applicable then I think the asker should be rewarded for doing that -- they've put at least as much time into doing that as it takes to write an answer (indeed, my highest scoring questions have much more effort in them than my highest scoring answers). However, that's the "official correct answer", so I'm giving you a +1.